# Template for Sub Project A, B, C with multiple Lists in SPS 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-templates

I have been asked to develop a SharePoint Publishing Site for project managers in our organization.

Wherein they can create multiple projects. 
Example: Project A, Project B, Project C.

It should show all the required SPS Lists, which I have created and are visible on the main site level.

Thus need to have a template that can be used again n again that shows all the Lists, so Project Manager can start feeding the data as and when needed and update the relevant Project.

Please check the Template Diagram for better understanding.
[image]

Looking for assistance on how to do it:

- What are the areas to look up
- How to design the Template.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are you planning to develop using CSOM, JSOM or SSOM?

Comment: Egidiocs, good question

But may not a good answer, I`m not a developer and just know a bit by reading articles and using existing Javascript codes that can make my day.

Please suggest what ur view as the optimum approach in my case?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Edidiocs, I was checking more info on CSOM and wondering if that would be applicable in my case?

Comment: Experts any suggestions?